# Friendly_ID Scoped WITH History?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I was wondering how I can set a scope, AND have history? This is the code I have right now:

```
friendly_id :name, use: :scoped, :scope => :project
```

How can I change it to have it save history as well as be scoped?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't find the answer by now, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
friendly_id :name, use: [:scoped, :history], scope: :project
```

Though as far as I know this would only work with the 5.x versions of friendly_id.